# Font: Is British Baskerville typeface available in TeXLive 2010

Tags: fonts, texlive, typefaces

I would like to know if the British Baskerville typeface is available in TeXLive2010 (i.e. freely). If yes, which package to load?

Thanks...

Comment: TL2011 is available since a few days ago.

Comment: Good to hear. I will stick to TL2010 for some more time though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{baskervald}% part of TeXLive/MiKTeX
\begin{document}

Some text in baskerville
\itshape
Some text in baskerville

\end{document}
```

read http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/baskervaldadf.html for more informations.

Comment: Thanks. I have compiled the code with pdfTeX and it works. Anything special about the class scrartcl? I read it is a KOMA–Script class article. I can run the above code with the default article class also. 1vote up.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: The KOMA classes have a lot extensions which the default standard classes lack