# Baskerville font selection

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Font: Is British Baskerville typeface available in TeXLive 2010](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23758/font-is-british-baskerville-typeface-available-in-texlive-2010)

I'd like to use the font baskerville with latex to make a long document but have come across some confusion. After a couple of google searches I have found a way to install the font with latex but it looks confusing. Before I go down the wrong path I thought I'd check here to find the best way.

Comment: Does it have to be Baskerville itself, or can you use the ADF Baskervald clone, which may already be installed for use on your system?

Comment: search for Baskerville in above right input field and you'll get an example

Comment: That is an option I didn't know about. It is for scientfic writing so there are some special symbols I'll need. I'll look at baskervald.

Comment: Does this question still expect an answer of some kind?