# What is this font?

Tags: fonts, book-design

I'm trying to write my texts using a font like the image below, from an old book. Does anybody here know what is that font?

[image]

Using Baskerville as @Papiro suggested I got this (the math font is a little bit different):

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the name of the text or sth, for Google-ish purposes? Someone googling for the font might want to try searching by the title of the book. As the question stands, it is going to be extremely hard to search. Oh, +1 for the question!

Comment: If you look at the document properties of the PDF file, you should be able to see the fonts.

Comment: It is a scanned paper and I can not see any properties on the file. By the way, it is from a paper of P.J. Hilton.

Comment: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture) (especially comments to question).

Comment: @Speravir, thanks but my PDF does not contain embeded font, it is from an image. Also, those pages does not recognize my image. Thanks.

Comment: If it's a paper, it might help to know what journal it was published in.

Comment: First make a shorter screenshot version. You get an error message from WhatTheFont, which tells you there is a 100 characters limit. You may after still get an error though.

Comment: This text is from P.J. Hilton, An Introduction to Homotopy Theory, Cambridge University Press, 1953, pp. 97. In the book, there is no information about the font used.

Comment: @Speravir, it is not working. I tried with only two words but no success.

Comment: For others: http://books.google.com/books?id=hDg8AAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=An+Introduction+to+Homotopy+Theory&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Seems to be “Baskerville”: https://www.google.com/search?q=typeface+cambridge+university+press&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Baskerville font is available in TexLive... see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23758/font-is-british-baskerville-typeface-available-in-texlive-2010

Comment: @Papiro, I've just edited the post.

Comment: Sigur your second screenshot is the proof, that is is in fact a version of Baskerville typeface! I say version because over time there were slightly different derivatives developed, cf. En. Wikipedia: [Baskerville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baskerville). Both in MiKTeX and TeX Live there are `gfsbaskerville`, `librebaskerville` and `baskervald`, and see also `newtx` documentation.

Comment: while I agree that it's OK to close this question, I'm sorry to say that the answer »Baskerville« is off by almost an entire century. The typeface we have here is a typical example of the so-called »Scotch Roman« family from the mid-1800s (Baskerville died in the 1770s!). Digital renditions of that style have been done by [Nick Shinn](http://goo.gl/3vsA2), [URW](http://goo.gl/4M7DA) & countless others. Knuth's Computer Modern is of course one of them, too. You may also like [TeX Gyre Schola](http://goo.gl/36Adf) and [Miller](http://goo.gl/fldYX), which have a somewhat ›friendlier‹ appearance.